# Batching and chunking excel files (Laravel Maatwebsite library)

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv, maatwebsite-excel

According to the [documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import), you can use batch to load files. You also can chunk the data in case of large files.

Chunking:

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load('file.csv')->chunk(250, function($results)
{
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
});
```

Batch import:

```
Excel::batch('app/storage/uploads', function($rows, $file) {

    // Explain the reader how it should interpret each row,
    // for every file inside the batch
    $rows->each(function($row) {

        // Example: dump the firstname
        dd($row->firstname);

    });

});
```

I have a series of large files, and I was wondering if it is possible to chain these 2 functions together. The problem is that both function requires 2 variables (second one being a _callback), I am lost as to how to chain it together.

The only thing that seems to work now for me is something like this, but I doubt it actually does anything:

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->batch('files', function($rows, $file){
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Excel::batch(request()->file, function($rows, $file) {
                Excel::filter('chunk')->selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($file)->chunk($this->chunkSize, function($results) {

                    foreach ($results as $row) {

                    }            
                }, $this->shouldQueue);
            });
```

You can define the chunkSize and shouldQueue values.